# Problems with width on header bar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a "bar" that stretches over the top of my web page (like Facebook). Then I have some navigational links on the right. However if you resize the page and then use the horizontal scrollbar the red background is missing.

http://jsfiddle.net/ejJnL/embedded/result/

http://jsfiddle.net/ejJnL/

```
<div class="header-container">
    <div class="header">
        <ul class="main-navigation">
            <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header-container {
    background-color: red;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}

.header {
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
}

.header img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.main-navigation {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.main-navigation li {
    float: left;
}

.main-navigation a {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Because you're setting the width in a child element. `width: 960px;`

Comment: But the color is set on the element (parent) which is width:100%?

Comment: Exactly, the parent stretches to the max width available at its execution(which may or may not be 960px), then the child comes in and extends the width.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's right - try it out add a bg color to .header

Comment: http://www.impressivewebs.com/width-100-percent-css/

Answer (score 0):

```
.header-container {
    background-color: red;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed:
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

1. Fix the position and declare it attached to the left and right edges of the viewport as shown above.
2. You don't need declarations of width: 100% or height: 100% as `div` are already block elements and will fill their containers.
3. You should declare `body { margin:0}` if you want the bar to extend to the page edges.
4. You should probably use `max-width` not `width` for your `.header` so the menu still shows in a small window.
5. You may also want to add an `overflow: none` to the `.header-container`

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/SbpZG/

Fixed width on the `.header-container` and `position: relative` on the `.main-navigation`